# Deleting a row based on the max value in SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

[image]

I have `@RankTable` table which contains debit of different customers. From this I want to delete for each customer who has the highest rank.

```
Declare @RankTable Table
(
   Customer_ID int,
   Debit decimal(18,2),
   Transaction_Date datetime,
   Sales_Master_ID int,
   Rank int,
   Rank1 int
)
Insert into @RankTable
  Select *,row_number()over(partition by (Customer_ID)  Order By 
    Customer_ID)as Rank1 
From @tempTable


Select  Customer_ID,Debit,Transaction_Date ,Sales_Master_ID,Rank1 from 
@RankTable Order By Customer_ID
```

*I expect the output of the above table is: 
I want to delete customer who is having maximum rank.
For ex:I want to delete the row of Customer_ID = 4 which is having Rank1 = 20 (like this for all customers), but I can't delete*

Comment: Most people here want sample data and expected result as formatted text, not as images. (Besides, I can't read that tiny image text.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a CTE, which targets the highest ranking record for each customer.

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Customer_ID ORDER BY Rank1 DESC) rn
    FROM @RankTable
)

DELETE
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1;
```

Comment: Can i ask you one more thing? If Suppose I want to get Maximum of Rank-1 for each customer ie.
ex: Customer_ID=4 and Rank1=20 
I expect the output As :  I Want to delete  all the row of Customer_ID=4 and remain only one row .
 Row Which contains Maximum Rank -1 (that means the row which conatin RANK =19  for Customer_ID=4)
For  this how to change the above answer.Is there any way for this??

Comment: Change my `WHERE` clause to `WHERE rn <> 2` ... keep in mind my answer assumes throughout that there are no ties anywhere for the `Rank1` value.  If there could be ties, then it changes things.

Answer (score 0):

This will work-

```
DELETE A
FROM @RankTable A
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT ID,MAX(Rank1) Rank1
    FROM @RankTable 
    GROUP BY ID
) B
ON A.id = B.id and A.Rank1 = B.Rank1
```